# Setting bookmark in QGIS properly

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, bookmarks, layout-manager

I have some trouble setting the bookmark in the canvas the way it fits perfectly the extent in the layout manager.

The easiest way would be to be able to set the bookmark in the layout manager itself. But I didn’t find this option.

How do you set the bookmarks?

Is there another easy option to print the same extent again after changing the data? The only other solution I can think of is to create a new layout for every extent, which I think is a bit unpractical.

Comment: Without knowing your project details I'd only make a general suggestion that you look at how the Map Atlas might be used.  It is also easy to duplicate layouts in layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It is also more a workaround but at least it works:

1. Set the proper extent in the layout manager
2. Create a new spatial bookmak in the canvas. Replace the extent values with those from the map in the layout manager. (Watch out: No thousand seperators (‘) are accepted, they have to be deleted.)
3. Switch between the different bookmarks in the layout manager. Rotate the map manually (add the rotation in to the bookmark-name!)

I would still be happy to find a easier way to do it. Ideas welcome!